# Why does my GET query with cURL and Python requests redirects me to an "Internet Explorer not supported" page despite Firefox user-agent?

Tags: web-scraping, curl, python-requests

I am trying to automate some work load with Python requests or cURL (can't use browser automation like Selenium), but I can't seem to get the login page to load properly.

Whether I use a Python requests.get() or a straight copy of my Firefox's cURL, it loads a page telling me that I can't use this page with Internet Explorer and I can't figure out why.

When I output my response's content to a file, I can see in the source code that the script checking for Internet Explorer seems to look at the user agent, which I have set as my Firefox UA :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oktaDomain = 'https://selfservice.dfamilk.com';

    var isInternetExplorer = false;
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0)
        isInternetExplorer = true;

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) 
        isInternetExplorer = true;

    if (isInternetExplorer) {
        const ieMessage = document.getElementById("internet-explorer-message");
        ieMessage.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

The copied cURL request is as follow :

```
curl 'https://sso.dfamilk.com/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1'
```

Any hint?

Thank you

I would hope to use Python requests in a session to load the login page and then go through the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP curl request is not the URL in the copied curl.  `https://sso.dfamilk.com/`.

**UPDATE:** The response with and without the sso subdomain were the same.

Your request headers are not working. Your request header looks like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: dfamilk.com
Accept: */*
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
```

I made this request and got a 200 HTTP status.

```
$header = [];
$header[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0';
$header[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$header[] = 'DNT: 1';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$header[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
$header[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$header[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none';
$header[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sso.dfamilk.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
echo "\nheader out: " . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

And the request header looked like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: sso.dfamilk.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

The body of the response was 4,782 bytes of binary data.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 01:01:29 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: ResetPasswordReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.dfamilk.com; expires=Fri, 04 Nov 2022 01:01:29 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9fXoN5jHCXs=CfDJ8Ltn3evoeUFInSP2VHv_Bg96A0Yx1ooD3BPAB6XPft895dUHtS-GX2igEl_31Vzw_MK5Zy5Yxveusk8KSFrHCgL6ldCXBe28-labcLPvRZipfv2YRBmeupdHXnvIcqGbG-9K9s91idTVcGP68yG2ruo; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=758dc96b7f82a7096182971f997ca2b723f6e549d364dae23fee712647d199a1;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sso.dfamilk.com
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinitySameSite=758dc96b7f82a7096182971f997ca2b723f6e549d364dae23fee712647d199a1;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sso.dfamilk.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

And your python code would look like:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
}

response = requests.get('https://sso.dfamilk.com/', headers=headers)
```